# Get rid of the [stocks] and [stock] tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I currently see 188 questions tagged [stocks](/questions/tagged/stocks) which all seem to be about the stock market. I haven't found any that use that tag in a way that is really programming related. Many of the questions seem to be in need of cleanup/closure too (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285288/historical-data-with-pe-ratio-eps-dividend-yield-etc).

Is there any use to the tag, or can it safely be destroyed?

I just noticed there are also 172 questions tagged [stock](/questions/tagged/stock) as well which seem split between inventory management and stock market data sources...

And another, [stockquotes](/questions/tagged/stockquotes) on 89 questions.

Comment: I find value in the tag. It is an interesting piece of information in my opinion to see the group of those questions. Although there may be bad questions in there, there are also some good ones. Working with stocks is a rather common practice for programming and I would like to see the tags stay. Perhaps they could be associated through a synonym.

Comment: It seems similar to tagging questions about displaying rows of data in columns with \[sports\] or \[baseball\] because that's where the data came from. Do stocks present unique programming problems or can they be dismissed from most questions as the source of the data and let the questions focus on the type of data and the problem at hand?

Comment: Most of the time the tools and requirements are going to be different when dealing with stock data than with other sources of data. The context would still be present in the question and answers, it would just make it a little harder to group them. I think that burninating useless tags is a good endeavor, but I feel there is value in this tag, and once removed it would be gone.

Comment: Those tags provide information, what is the program for, and for SO scope it's irrelevant. Vote for burnination. There are  also [tag:trading] and [tag:finance] tags. The same barrel.

Comment: Stock market prediction is a pretty significant machine learning field. Now "stock(s)" might not be most descriptive tag name for questions about this, but don't just sever that connection. And there may be other questions where it's useful to know that it's about stocks (?). Bottom line - the questions need to be handled on a case-by-case basis, the result of this process should make it clear whether or not it should be kept and/or that it needs to be replaced with a more descriptive tag name in some cases.

Comment: @Dukeling I am cautious because as you say there are possibly scenarios where it's a useful grouping. That being said, I haven't seen anything like that in the questions I looked at with those tags. If anyone can find a (or preferably a few) examples worth some sort of \[stock-market\] tag and post an answer here with them in it and a good non-ambiguous tag name, I'd certainly vote it up.

Comment: @jball [The most upvoted ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stocks?sort=votes&pageSize=50) are mostly off topic (asking for a library / tool). [Here's an algorithm question about stock prices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1663545). Specific to stock prices? Probably not, but that's the way it's usually asked, so it may be easier to find it with the tag. While maybe not a particularly good question, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19302365) is kind of what I'm talking about. I don't have a good tag name replacement in mind. I'll leave a more in-depth analysis to anyone up to it.